# How to extract C source code from .so file?

Tags: c, linux, extract, decompiling, shared-libraries

I am working on previously developed software and source code is compiled as linux shared libraries (.so) and source code is not present. Is there any tool which can extract source code from the linux shared libraries?

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 20):

There isn't. Once you compile your code there is no trace of it left in the binary, only machine code.

Some may mention decompilers but those don't extract the source, they analyze the executable and produce some source that should have the same effect as the original one did.

Comment: Decompilers produce some pretty gawd-awful code. The variable names are meaningless and there are no useful comments. You might as well be staring at the assembly.

Comment: @Christ I agree. I didn't get to use Hex-rays (which I heard is quite good) but the others I tried were awful.

Answer (score 6):

You can try disassembling the object code and get the machine code mnemonics.

`objdump -D --disassembler-options intel sjt.o`  to get Intel syntax assembly

`objdump -D --disassembler-options att sjt.o` or `objdump -D sjt.o` to get AT&T syntax assembly

But the original source code could never be found. You might try to reverse the process by studying and reconstruct the sections. It would be hell pain.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I work for Hex-Rays SA.

The Hex-Rays decompiler is the only commercially available decompiler I know of that works well with **real-life** x86 and ARM code. It's true that you don't get the original source, but you get something which is equivalent to it. If you didn't strip your binary, you might even get the function names, or, with some luck, even types and local variables. However, even if you don't have symbol info, you don't have to stick to the first round of decompilation. The Hex-Rays decompiler is *interactive* - you can rename any variable or function, change variable types, create structure types to represent the structures in the original code, add comments and so on. With a little work you can recover *a lot*. And quite often what you need is not the whole original file, but some critical algorithm or function - and this Hex-Rays can usually provide to you.

Have a look at the [demo](http://hexblog.com/decompilation/video/vd1.html) [videos](http://www.ccso.com/files/hexraysdemo.swf) and the [comparison](http://www.hex-rays.com/compare.shtml) [pages](http://www.hex-rays.com/hexcomp12.shtml). Still think "staring at the assembly" is the same thing?

Comment: Hex-Rays seems to be commercial decompiler. Is there any open source decompiler?

Comment: There are a few, such as REC or Boomerang, see [here](http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/MachineCodeDecompilers). But none of them are suitable for real-life use IMO.

Comment: What about IDA ? AFAIK, it was quite good at decompiling and there is a free (old) version nowadays

Comment: can I use trial version of Hex-Rays decompiler

Answer (score -3):

No.  In general, this is impossible.  Source is not packaged in compiled objects or libraries.