# Running .so on Mac OSX

Tags: java, c, linux, macos, macos-high-sierra

I've hired been for a company that uses Java as their primary language and the primary project we use is a shared library developed with C and compiled for Linux, so its extension is .so. We do not have the source code, so my question is:

How can I use a shared library .so in Mac OSX? I need to recompile a project in Java that use this shared library. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You may be out of luck according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933057/how-to-extract-c-source-code-from-so-file).

Comment: You're not going to be able to reuse this shared library.  While Linux and Mac OS/X are Unix derivatives, they are very different and will not be compatible at this level.

Comment: Any reason why you can't run a VM with Linux on that and try and get the SO to work there?

Comment: @Makoto i don't like VM, isn't fluid and this get me Crazy hahaha

Comment: Well...not sure what else to tell you.  Hopefully you're not driven too crazy.